# Format Date Time in Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I should format my datetime value in javascript to this format yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss

I tried this

```
  var btf = new Date(value.createDate);
  var billingTimeFormatted = btf.getFullYear() + "-" +  btf.getMonth()  + "-" + btf.getDate() + " " + btf.getHours() + ":" + btf.getMinutes() + ":" + btf.getSeconds();
```

But it result to this

2017-8-31 02:00:00

1. month and date should be 2-digit (08 intead of 8)

What could be the best workaround?

*type on minutes is edited

Comment: You forgot the parentheses after `getMinutes`. If you don't mind adding another library, consider using moment.js.

Comment: `btf.getMinutes` => `btf.getMinutes()` Voting to close as typo.

Comment: sorry, yes it was just mistyped will edit it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing wrong with your code. Javascript returns the integer < 10 in single digit only. Format it to string of 2 with a function.

```
    function formatWithZero(val)
    {

     // as per comment by @RobG below, return ('0'+val).slice(-2) will also 
     // do the same thing in lesser lines of code. It works and can be used.
      var value = val.toString();
      if(value.length > 1)
                   return value;

        var str = "00"+value;
        return str.slice(str.length-2,str.length); ;
    }

//I am using Date.now(), you can use your value.
    var btf = new Date(Date.now());

      var billingTimeFormatted = btf.getFullYear() + "-" +  formatWithZero(btf.getMonth())  + "-" + formatWithZero(btf.getDate()) + " " + formatWithZero(btf.getHours()) + ":" + formatWithZero(btf.getMinutes()) + ":" + formatWithZero(btf.getSeconds());
        alert(billingTimeFormatted);
```

Comment: I guess this too will work in hours minutes and seconds

Comment: Yes..it does..It should be a valid date containing these values.

Comment: The entire function body can be `return ('0'+val).slice(-2)`.

Comment: Yes, but i did not want to check when its length was ok. I am also putting your suggestion in the function as comment.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot `()` for `getMinutes()`, to have 2 digits :

```
var btf = new Date();    
var currentMonth = btf.getMonth();
if (currentMonth < 10) { currentMonth = '0' + currentMonth; }
var billingTimeFormatted = btf.getFullYear() + "-" +  currentMonth  + "-" + btf.getDate() + " " + btf.getHours() + ":" + btf.getMinutes() + ":" + btf.getSeconds();
```